# How to create Kafka Topic name on run based on some value field

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I have a requirement, where I have to create the topic name based on different values coming in for a field in the `<Value object>`. So that all the `records<K,V>` with similar field values goes in `Topic_<Field>`. How can I do it using kstream?

Comment: Enable auto topic creation and while writing using stream write to your new topic

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka 1.1.0, you can use `branch()` to split a stream into substreams and than write the different substreams into different topics by adding a different sink operator (ie, `to()`) to each substream.

Kafka 2.0 (will be released in June), adds a new "dynamic routing" feature that simplifies this scenario. Compare: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-303%3A+Add+Dynamic+Routing+in+Streams+Sink

Note, that Kafka Streams requires that sink topics are created manually -- Kafka Streams does not create any sink topic for you. As mentioned by @Hemant, you could turn on auto topic creation. However, it's not recommended in general (one reason is you might want different configs for different topic, but via auto creation all would be created with the same default config).

Also note, that a rogue application could DDoS your Kafka cluster if auto topic creation is enabled by sending "bad data" into the application and thus creating hundreds or thousands of topics (by specifying a different topic name for each message). Thus, it's risky and not recommended to enable auto topic creation but to create topics manually.